# Custom import package Python

Tags: python-2.7, import, module, package

I am making a import package and I keep running into a problem when I try and import and use the package. Primarily when I try to run it.

```
import mypackage
```

once I import it I can use it I dont get any errors upon importing it, however when I go to use it I get an error that says

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

In a folder that I have named myfolder which is located in my current working directory i have a empty **init**.py file as well as two other .py files which contain the functions i have one called test.py and another called testing.py.... my problem isnt importing them but when I go to use them I get the TypeError.

the folders structure is as follows,

```
current working directory
 -Mypackage
  -__init__.py
  -test.py
  -testing.py
```

I import it like this,

```
from Mypackage import test
```

I use it like this,

```
test(stuff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn how to use modules in python. When you import mypackage into your script it imports a module which has two scripts in it. Let's say they are first.py and second.py . Now if you use something like

```
from mypackage import first
```

And then you use a function named `func` like this

```
first.func()
```

Then it should work.

In short either import all the functions from your module or use dot notation to reference these functions. More on module can be read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: I am doing so I just cant seem to get it to work, I have them importing fine but when I go to use them like I usually do when the function is present in the kernel it doesnt work.

Comment: What is kernal referenced for ? Post your folder structure and also one of your files from module and how are you importing it

Comment: Edit the question to make it more specific like directory structure and how are you using the module function because I think the provided way should work.

Comment: Use test.function_name() instead of just test() . test is a module test is not a function.